# How to wait until views have been added to layout? -Android

Tags: android, android-layout, refresh

Okay, so what I have been trying to do is this:
first update views on my layout and then move the scrollview (where the layout is) to right place. The code for scrolling to right place is working fine and there is no problem without updating.

*Problem:
When I edit something  and then need to delete all views and add those back to layout my normally working code for scrolling to right place won't scroll anywhere (and thats because at that time there is "nothing on layout") And this is when running normally the app*

So I have been debugging and the reason I found for this is that the layout keeps updating:
there is all those views added but the layout is not yet getting it's real size and layout.getHeight() gives value 0. I have been trying **scrollview.invalidate();** and **layout.invalidate();**

Is there something I can call that would wait until the layout gets it real size or can I call somehing to tell layout to get it?

Edit: added the problem

Comment: It's unclear what your actual problem is. You say "the reason I found for this" but didn't actually say what "this" actually is. Are you getting a certain type of error? A crash? Views not displaying properly? It would help if you provided your code and stated exactly what the problem is. Also it would help to know if the issue is on Activity start up or after the app is already running.

Comment: Might this be related? [Callback after all child Views from XML have been added to ViewGroup?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40183648/905686)