# Callback after all child Views from XML have been added to ViewGroup?

Tags: android, xml, callback, android-custom-view

I was writing a custom `ViewGroup` and came across the following problem:

The `ViewGroup` should be usable by specifying properties in XML only.
However, I want to do some internal initialization in code after the `ViewGroup` has been created and all its child `View`s from XML have been added (that is, when the layout inflator has added all the child `View`s of a `ViewGroup` specified in XML).

All I found related to this are recommendations to use `getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(...)`.
However, this is called at least after each child `View` is added and also after resuming an app etc. So it does not even make it possible to detect the moment when all child `View`s have been added.

Is there a method called after all child `View`s have been added to a `ViewGroup`?

Related: [When are child views added to Layout/ViewGroup from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17334078/905686)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a callback: `View.onFinishInflate()`.
From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) (which also has a section "Implementing a Custom View" describing all the callbacks):

> Finalize inflating a view from XML. This is called as the last phase
>   of inflation, **after all child views have been added.**

Simply override the method in your custom `ViewGroup`:

```java
public class MyViewGroup extends ViewGroup {

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        doMyInitialization();
    }
}
```